# Simulate / Mock a MySql Database for Unit Testing

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

For our applications we have created a series of healthchecks. One of these health checks checks whether or not a MySql database is up and running. In order to unit test this functionality I need to mock or simulate a database and run the health check against it.

To establish a connection to the MySql database being checked, we are using `DriverManager.getConnection()`. So we first tried to mock the return value of `getConnection()`. However, that is a static method and Mockito is unable to mock it. Then we turned to Powermock because it is able to mock static methods. Unfortunately, we found it to be poorly supported with JUnit5 and we had to clutter up our pom with a lot of dependencies. Not to mention the code was becoming overly complicated. In the end, we decide to look for other options besides mocking.

Basically, our health check just needs to make sure that the MySQL url, username, and password are correct and the database will accept a connection. Ideally, our unit tests would reflect these requirements.

So, our next idea is to use an In-Memory database, like this [**one**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database) from Baeldung. This seems like a great option but I'm worried it won't behave in the same way a real MySQL database will. Is there a way to create an In-memory MySQl database and establish a connection with `DriverManager.getConnection()`? This would effectively simulate our real life health check

Comment: Another option is the jcabi mysql maven plugin: http://mysql.jcabi.com/ please note version > 0.7 doesn't work on Windows. (I will expand in an answer)

Comment: If you really want to test MySQL, then why not spin up a dedicated test database somewhere?

Comment: Why not just setup a local mysql database, and use that for testing? Provide the database options as a setting to the framework.

Comment: Setting up a local DB is a bit challenging as tests are not portable.

Comment: This is for the purpose of unit testing so must run anywhere, anytime

Comment: No, don't do this at all.  Think about it - you want to test whether you can tell if a database is up and running, but without a database.  This makes about as much sense as test-driving a car by tracing a route on a map with your finger.  There is no benefit in having this test in your test suite.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem But we are testing the logic that is checking whether or not the database is up. To do this we need a database that is always up.. or mock/simulate one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "logic".  I can't imagine anything much more than a single line, that checks the return value from `DriverManager.getConnection()`.  It's kind of a waste of time unit testing anything that doesn't have some kind of branching or looping logic.  But maybe you can clarify your question by posting the code of the method you want to unit test.  If there's actual logic in there, I may be able to make some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the mysql jcabi maven plugin: mysql.jcabi.com

Please note version > 0.7 doesn't work on Windows.

This will actually setup an instance of MySQL, so it allows for one to test very mysql specific stuff, though the first run is slow.

So, a couple of questions will help drive your answer: are you doing anything highly MySQL specific?  Do you want your app to be portable to other DBs?

If the answer is yes to the first one and no to the second one, probably use the jcabi plugin.

If the answer is no to the first, and yes to the second, you're probably pretty safe using H2.

If the answer is yes to both, you've got bigger problems :).

I generally try to keep my code away from DB vendor specificity and use libraries like JPA to abstract this.  I can then assume that JPA (and impl) has tested across the supported DBs, and I'm good enough to run unit and integration tests with an in-memory DB like H2.

I generally also have some end-to-end testing in a prod-like env with the same DB setup as prod, in order to cover any vendor-specific quirks.

Comment: Our healthcheck will have different methods for different databases. So yes it will be portable, but if we need to check the health of another db, we will write another test

Comment: I'd suggest you use the jcabi maven plugin then.

Comment: How would I specify version 0.7. I tried to add `<version>0.7</version>` to the plugin element in the POM, but the maven build said it could not be found.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcabi/jcabi-mysql-maven-plugin/0.7